# How to set space in the Title

Tags: spacing, report, setspace

i want to set the space between the title lines

```
\newcommand{\reporttitle}{ this is a title with a lot of text bla bla bla}
```

i used

```
\usepackage{setspace}
 \setstretch{2}
```

but nothing happens

```
\newcommand{\reporttitle}{ this is a title with \setstretch{2} a lot of text bla bla
```

my entire preambule

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article} % Pour une impression recto verso, utilisez plutôt ce documentclass : %\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,final]{article}

\usepackage[english,francais]{babel} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} \usepackage{setspace} \usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage[french]{varioref} \newcommand{\reporttitle}{ title with some text and bla bla}     % Titre \newcommand{\reportauthor}{james \textsc{lebois} \\ didier \textsc{mopli}} % Auteur \newcommand{\reportsubject}{Stage d'application} % Sujet \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} \setlength{\parskip}{1ex} % Espace entre les paragraphes

%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} \usepackage{caption} \usepackage{subcaption}

% add an extra subsection \usepackage{titlesec} \usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection] \renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}} \renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{} \titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter \renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%   {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%   {-1em}%   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}} \renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}% {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%   {-1em}%   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}} \def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4} \def\toclevel@paragraph{5} \def\toclevel@paragraph{6} \def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}} \def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}} \def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}} \makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}



\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\reporttitle},%
    pdfauthor={\reportauthor},%
    pdfsubject={\reportsubject},%
    pdfkeywords={rapport} {vos} {mots} {clés} }  \usepackage{newunicodechar}  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}


    \begin{document}

  \include{title}
  \cleardoublepage % Dans le cas du recto verso, ajoute une page blanche si besoin
  \tableofcontents % Table des matières
  \sloppy          % Justification moins stricte : des mots ne dépasseront pas des    paragraphes
  \cleardoublepage
  \include{Abstract}
  \include{Resume}
  \include{remerciements}
  \cleardoublepage
  \include{intro}
  \cleardoublepage
  \include{partie1}
  \cleardoublepage
  \include{partie2}
  \cleardoublepage
   \include{partie3}
  \cleardoublepage
  \include{partie4}
  \cleardoublepage
  \include{concl}
  \cleardoublepage
  \include{references}
\end{document}
```

i'm just a newbie at lateX , any hints ?

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-working example, with preamble, begin/end{document], &c.?

Comment: @Bernard ok i have added my entire preambule, it seems that i'm am an expert in lateX but i have just copy and paste them , i can't explain it .... a question : is the text that i have posted worked for you ??

Comment: It can't possibly work for Bernard because you haven't posted a complete document: there's no `\begin{document}`, no content and no `\end{document}`.  Take a look [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for some help with creating a minimal example.

Comment: Why are you not using `\title{<Title of your document>}` and then `\maketitle` in your document?

Comment: @cfr i don't know what should i include , i have just begin using lateX ... i have added the begin and end section

Comment: That's why I gave you a link to some help with this. It will help you not only make an example suitable for posting here, but all help you learn the most important method of diagnosing and resolving problems with TeX. Honestly, it is worth reading.

Comment: The basic idea is to give us code (as little as possible - just enough) which we can copy, paste and compile to *reproduce the problem you are asking about*. Right now, we cannot compile your example at all. Nor is it minimal. You can test if the example is suitable by trying to compile it and seeing if it produces the problem. Make sure it does not depend on files we don't have, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no real idea what you are trying to do or what the code fragments are intended to achieve. But perhaps this will help somewhat. Here is some annotated code which is closer, at least, to being minimal. It demonstrates the use of `\maketitle`, `\title` and `\author`.

Comments:

- I'm not sure what the purpose of `\reporttitle` etc. is. If you need to access this information after creating the title, take a look at `titling`.
- Be careful not to load packages twice, especially with different options.
- Don't specify a driver to `graphicx` unless you need to. For pdfTeX, you don't. Let it detect the driver it needs automatically.
- `hyperref` should be one of the last packages loaded.
- Don't mix manual customisation with a package designed to customise the same document elements, or mix different packages designed to customise the same elements. For example, if you use `titlesec`, stick to that. Don't then customise `\paragraph` manually: use the interface `titlesec` provides.
- Use semantic-markup whenever possible e.g. use `\maketitle` rather than a home-brewed solution.
- Don't reinvent the wheel: use existing commands and packages when you can.
- Load as many packages as you need and no more than you need. For example, use `titling` rather than going into the home-brewing business, but don't load `titlesec` if you want to redefine section titles manually.
- Don't use `\sloppy`. Certainly, do not use it for your entire document. If absolutely necessary, when the content is finalised, you *might*, if pushed, need to typeset a particular paragraph sloppily. But you don't want your entire document to be typeset sloppily as sloppy typesetting is, well, sloppy. It is not good.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\reporttitle}{title with some text and bla bla}     % Titre
\newcommand{\reportauthor}{james \textsc{lebois} and didier \textsc{mopli}}

% % add an extra subsection - if using this and customising section title formats, USE TITLESEC's INTERFACE
% \usepackage{titlesec}
% \titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
% \newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
% \renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
% \renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}
% \titleformat{\subsubsubsection}   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{} \titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
% % if using titlesec, use titlesec to redefine e.g. \paragraph etc.

% no need to pass a driver to graphicx for pdfTeX - better to auto-detect
% \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}% should be one of the last packages loaded

\begin{document}

\title{\reporttitle}% note that putting the title as an argument would work just as well
\author{\reportauthor}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: you give a huge information here thanks i'm learning new things on latex , i was able to write it correctly after deleting some packages i don't need and creating a latex document

Comment: @Frankenstein Glad it helped! The learning curve for LaTeX is generally described as 'steep' ;). But then it starts to make sense and feel natural....

Comment: yes especially when you want something elegant and professional , like my case ... but it seems very interresting and there are many resssource and support on the net , that helped a lot , thanks